# magnetic levitated tower - magnetic fields and tensile strengths of materials

Tags: electromagnetism

I was considering a system made from a stack of electromagnetically levitated platforms and wondering how you would go about comparing its tensile (and or compressive) strength to that of a solid material.

There is a similar question and answer here but it is scant on details:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/250746/tensile-strength-of-a-chain-of-electromagnets

I'm interested in whether it be 'practical' to make a structure with a tensile strength similar or better than say steel in this way? or a strength to density ratio better than a conventional material.

I think this is the same question as asking what strength of magnetic field would be required to tear a material apart.

On that basis:

Q1 **For a given platform size what stength of field is would be required to create a 'joint' at least as strong as if a solid steel bar was used instead?**

Q2 **What current would be needed to power the coil?**

I'm presuming it would have a 'base' level and increase current draw as strain increased up to some maximum beyond which something fails - the coil burns out or we cut the power and let the platform drop.

Is such a field readily achievable? I think we can generate a few 10s of Telsas in NMR scanners.

Assuming our best current efficiency how much power would such a device consume per platform at maximum stress?

### My thinking so far

So for this thought experiment consider a [tensometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_testing_machine) (or other device used to evaluate the tensile strength of a material (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensile_testing) but which does so using electromagnetic repulsion rather than a more common mechanical or hydraulic systrem.

For the tensometer the magnetic field could be distributed in the area around the sample so I think it is a workable design if not efficient.

Returning to the stack of platforms the same force would have to be concentrated into the area of the sample. I wonder if it might need to be so strong it would tear apart the materials that would be used to construct the platforms.

The power requirements would presumably be horrendous too.

I'd like to see an answer of this quality https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/37923/19065

I wonder also if you usefully make an existing structure weaker or stronger using such a mechanism. Think "polarize the hull plating".

I am assuming that each platform is an active component. They either generate power themselves or have power fed to them by wire or induction from the fields being used to support them.
They stabilize the platform above dynamically as in any number of examples on the net (e.g https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=magnetic+levitation)

Note: the mechanism is allowed to use diamagnetism (ie. superconductors). It need not rely entirely on electromagnets.

Further I'm assuming the design aims to constrain the fields as far as possible so that energy is focused on levitation via shielding and coupling effects.

Shielding is also necessary so that anything at the top or in an elevator to reach it (e.g. a person) would not be fried.

Thinking this way would it be possible to construct something that has a greater strength to weight ratio than the equivalent solid material would have.

Thinking about practical (though not necessarily sensible) applications consider:

- A magnetic levitating telescopic ladder
- A magnetic levitating car jack

These of course do not need the tensile strength of steel they only need to support
the weight of a person or a car so getting a bit more sci-fi consider:

- A tripod
- A cloud city
- A space elevator - taking this idea to the extreme
  (I believe the current estimate is we would need a tensile strength of around 150GPa for such a structure)

I'm thinking that we need to derive something like [magnetic pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_pressure) to match the units used for tensile strengths of materials.
That page has one equation for force an a coil with resistance in the denominator. For a superconductor that would tend to zero, so I assume that must break down somewhere or be otherwise inapplicable.
The other equation giving the pressure as proportional to the square of the field sounds more applicable.

A major practical obstacle is that magnetic fields follow a cube law rather than a square law so even more power is required to produce a strong one. But I'm not if this would affect the power requirements significantly.

Comment: What are the mechanical properties of the electromagnetically levitated platforms, and how are they "stacked up"?

Comment: I've deliberarely left the mechanical properties under specified. I'm not sure how it matters other than its contribution to the weight that has to be supported. It is some kind of platform with several parts that can generate magnetic fields which can be varied dynamically to stabilize the postion. Each platform levitates upon the platform beneath it.

Comment: Note: the mechanism is allowed to use diamagnetism (ie. superconductors). It need not rely entirely on electromagnetics.

Comment: This has been closed as opinion based but I think it is based on physics. If it would need a 100000T magnetic field for 10cm square platform it would be impractical. If it would take only 1T for a 10m square platfrom it would be hard but not necessarily impossible.

Comment: You shall clearly state your objective or provide examples of applications so people can relate and compare. If it is for the structural purpose to support gravity load only, then it could be possible, but how it to function, also its stability remains as the major concerns.

Comment: @r13 I provided several examples. It is established fact that you can levitate small loads indefinitely against gravity with a suitable power source. The aim of the question is to estabilish whether it is 'practical' to create an electrically powered meta-material that is stronger than a conventional mechanical design.
Stability is the easy part as demonstrated by existing small scale models. You have multiple electromagnets and vary the force on each to keep your load on station using feedback control.

Comment: @r13 that said I also picked a space elevator as an extreme example as that is something which is impractical with the tensile strength of existing known materials (with the possible exception of emerging materials like nanotubes). I am thinking about just the tensile strength aspect here and not a complete space elevator design as that has a great many other considerations, such as location / safely / stability / power source.

Comment: Show your calculations so people can inspect and compare.

Comment: @r13 The point of the question was to determine the calculations needed in the first place

Comment: Simply put, people, I for one, failed to understand what is in your head. You need some substance, or show your effort, to draw people to your question to help. So far there is none. Sorry.